# How to produce combinations from a list of tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

- How can I produce combinations from a `list` of `tuples`, where each tuple is a `string` at index 0, and a `list` at index 1?
- Given the following `list` of `tuples`:

```py
params = ['sn', 'tp', 'v1', 'temp', 'slew']

list_tuple = [('Serial Number', [12345]),
              ('Test Points', ['TestpointA', 'TestpointC']),
              ('Voltage_1', [3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 0.0]),
              ('Temperature Setpoint', [0, 60]),
              ('Slew_1', [200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400])]

# working nested loop
def what_i_want(test_tuple, params):
    for sn in test_tuple[0][1]:
            for tp in test_tuple[1][1]:
                for v in test_tuple[2][1]:
                    for temp in test_tuple[3][1]:
                        for slew in test_tuple[4][1]:
                            print(f'{params[0]}: ', sn)
                            print(f'{params[1]}: ', tp)
                            print(f'{params[2]}: ', v)
                            print(f'{params[3]}: ', temp)
                            print(f'{params[4]}: ', slew)
                            print('\n')

what_i_want(list_tuple, params)
```

produces **desired output**:

```
sn:  12345
tp:  TestpointA
v1:  3.0
temp:  0
slew:  200

sn:  12345
tp:  TestpointA
v1:  3.0
temp:  0
slew:  400
...
...
```

The length of `params` corresponds to the number of `tuples` within `list_tuple`, and this length can vary, which means the nested looping changes. The length of each `list` within the `tuple` can also vary (i.e. the `list` with `'Serial Number'` could be 3 or 4 elements long, instead of 1).

How can I produce the **desired output**, without the nested loops?

I unsuccessfully tried to use recursion to unpack `list_tuple` and call `params` by index.

```py
# not working recursive function
def not_working(list_tuple):
    for i in list_tuple:
        if isinstance(i, tuple):
            print(i[0])
            not_working(i[1])
        else:
            print(i)
            print('\n')


not_working(list_tuple)

[out]:

Serial Number
12345


Test Points
TestpointA


TestpointC


Voltage_1
3.0


3.3


3.6


0.0


Temperature Setpoint
0


60


Slew_1
200


400


800


1600


3200


6400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
data = [('Serial Number', [12345]), ('Test Points', ['TestpointA', 'TestpointC']), ('Voltage_1', [3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 0.0]), ('Temperature Setpoint', [0, 60]), ('Slew_1', [200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400])]
params = ['sn', 'tp', 'v1', 'temp', 'slew']
for i in itertools.product(*[b for _, b in data]):
  print('\n'.join(f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(params, i)))
  print('-'*20)
```

Output (first three results):

```
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:200
--------------------
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:400
--------------------
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:800
--------------------
...
```

While `itertools.product` is (perhaps) the cleanest solution to this problem, a simple recursive function with a generator can be used.

*What is the difference between `d` and `data`?* In the recursive function, `d` is mutated at every iteration by list slicing (`d[i+1:]`). Since the length of `d` decreases, and `len(d)` finds the length of the object `d` in declared in the scope of the function, it will not be finding the length of the list storing the original data, but the length of the current value passed to `combination`, which is decreasing at every call.

```
def combination(d, current = []):
   if len(current) == len(data):
     yield current
   else:
     for i, a in enumerate(d):
       for c in a: 
         yield from combination(d[i+1:], current = current+[c])
       

for i in combination([b for _, b in data]):
  print('\n'.join(f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(params, i)))
  print('-'*20)
```

Output (first three results):

```
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:200
--------------------
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:400
--------------------
sn:12345
tp:TestpointA
v1:3.0
temp:0
slew:800
--------------------
```